# How to set $stateParams based on variable in controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sockets

I want to change `socket.io` connection based on $state , so  when user change state i want to assign `$stateParams` to `searchEnv` so we can make that `socket` connection active and start receiving messages for that env. lets say if i have $state `app.dit` i want to set envId to `dit`. 
How can i achieve this task using angular $stateProvider ?

trying to implement one view and controller for $States instead of multiple.

Ctrl.js

```
var searchEnv = $stateParams.envId;

socket.on(searchEnv + 'Consumer', function(data) {
    $scope.event.push(data);
});
```

app.js

```
.state('app.dit', {
    url: '/dit/:envId',
    templateUrl: 'view/partials/dit.html',
    controller: 'DitCtrl'
})
.state('app.st', {
    url: '/st/:envId',
    templateUrl: 'view/partials/dit.html',
    controller: 'DitCtrl'
})
```

mainCtrl.js

```
$scope.tabs = [{
        heading: 'Home',
        route: 'app.home',
        active: true
    },
    {
        heading: 'DIT',
        route: 'app.dit',
        active: false
    },
    {
        heading: 'ST',
        route: 'app.st',
        active: false
    },
    {
        heading: 'UAT',
        route: 'app.uat',
        active: false
    },
    {
        heading: 'LSP',
        route: 'app.lsp',
        active: false
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can watch actions `$stateChangeStart` on `$scope` or on `$rootScope` in your `controller`

```
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
    function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options){ ... })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$state.includes` method:

```
//EXAMPLES

$state.$current.name = 'contacts.details.item';

// Using partial names
$state.includes("contacts"); // returns true
$state.includes("contacts.details"); // returns true
$state.includes("contacts.details.item"); // returns true
$state.includes("contacts.list"); // returns false
$state.includes("about"); // returns false
```

For more information, see [UI-Router $state API Reference - includes method](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.3.1/index.html#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_includes)